# show/hide dropdown menu on hover/mouseout using jquery

Tags: jquery

so i have a simple navbar with a dropdown menu for when a user hovers on the more tab.  i want to hide the dropdown menu when the user mouses out of the categories div.

problem is that when the user mouses into a ul li, the dropdown closes.  how can i set it so that the function ignores the ul li within the categories div.  tried categories > * but didn't work.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li>tab1</li>
    <li>tab2</li>
    <li id="moretab">more</li>
  </ul>
</div> 
<div id="categories">
  <ul>
    <li>cats</li>
    <li>dogs</li>
  </ul>
</div>

$("#moretab").hover(function(){
  $("#categories").css("visibility","visible"); 
});
$("#categories").mouseout(function() {
    $("#categories").css("visibility","hidden"); 
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest answer is how you would do it without jQuery: put the dropdown in the triggering element (e.g. dropdown list in a list item in the navigation list).

If you want something less straightforward, `mouseleave` might help.

Answer (score 20):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#moretab").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#categories").show(); 
  });

  $("#categories, #moretab").mouseleave(function(){
    $("#categories").hide(); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Jquery hover plugin includes both mouseenter and mouseleave function and following code works fine for me.

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.dropdown').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideDown('fast');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').slideUp('fast');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help ! Hide the "sub_menu" first.

```
//html

<ul>
 <li id = "menu"> <a  href ="#"> Settings </a>
   <ul id = "sub_menu">
   <li> <a  href ="#"> page 1</a></li>
   <li> <a  href ="#"> page 2</a></li>
   </ul>
 </li>
 <li>SomeLink</li>
 <li>SomeLink 2</li>
</ul>

//Javascript

        $("#menu").hover(function() {
            $("#sub_menu").show();
        }, function() {
            $("#sub_menu").hide();
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Few things:

- put the div inside of the "#moretab" so that mousing from the menu back to the "more" won't close it.
- add a delay from mouseleave, which is a preferable user experience

  ```
  <div id="navbar">
      <ul>
          <li>tab1</li>
          <li>tab2</li>
          <li id="moretab">more
              <div id="categories">
                  <ul>
                      <li>cats</li>
                      <li>dogs</li>
                  </ul>
              </div>
          </li>
      </ul>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#moretab").hover(function(){
      $("#categories").slideDown("fast");
      clearTimeout(debounce);
  });

  $("#moretab").mouseleave (function() {
      debounce = setTimeout(closeMenu,400);
  });

  var debounce;
  var closeMenu = function(){
      $("#categories").slideUp("fast");
      clearTimeout(debounce);
  }

  });
  </script>
  ```