# Unable to click dropdown item with jquery .hover

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Good Morning all. Hope you're having a good day. I have two buttons and corresponding menu items. The menu containers are hidden by default and should show only when the cursor hovers on the buttons.

The functionality seems to work except it doesn't let me click on them. It closes right away when I try to reach them. Its like its too close yet so far. I'm sure it is happening because I'm using `.hover()` on the button only. And whenever the cursor moves away from the button, the container hides as well. How can I fix it?

I have tried using `if statements`, `.hide() .show()` and `pure css` methods but nothing seems to work.

Here's the snippet:

```js
const list1Btn              = document.querySelector('.nav #by-list1');
const list2Btn             = document.querySelector('.nav #by-list2');
const list1Container        = document.querySelector('.nav .list1-container');
const list2Container       = document.querySelector('.nav .list2-container');

$(list1Btn).hover(() => {
     $(list1Container).stop().fadeToggle();
})

$(list2Btn).hover(() => {
    $(list2Container).stop().fadeToggle();
})
```

```css
.nav{
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}
.nav a{
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
}

.nav .list1-container,
.nav .list2-container{
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0px;
    background-color: #2e3032;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 500px;
    display: none;
}

.nav .dropdown-flex{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav .dropdown-flex .dropdown-column{
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 50%;
    padding: 14px 35px;
}

.nav .dropdown-flex .dropdown-column div{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #45484a;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.nav .dropdown-flex .dropdown-column a{
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
}

.nav .dropdown-flex .dropdown-column:nth-child(2) div:last-child a{
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #ef969a;
}

.nav a{
    margin-left: 35px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #c7cacc;
    font-weight: 900;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1.4px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
    <a id="by-list1">View List 1</a>
    <a id="by-list2">View List 2</a>

    <div class="list1-container">
        <div class="dropdown-flex">
            <div class="dropdown-column">
                <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list2-container">
        <div class="dropdown-flex">
            <div class="dropdown-column">
                <div><a href="#">Item 7</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Item 8</a></div>
                <div><a href="#">Item 9</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Put the button and the menu inside the same container, and apply the `.hover()` effect on the whole container. This way, even if you leave the button and start hovering over the menu, you're still hovering the same container, so it won't fade out.

Comment: @JeremyThille Hey man. I don't think I can do that. The button is more like a navigation anchor link inside navigation menu. And the container is a totally separate item.

Comment: They are only this way because you designed your markup this way. Nothing prevents you from moving the `<a>View List</a>` inside `<div class="list-container">`

Comment: Check this out: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989078/show-hide-dropdown-menu-on-hover-mouseout-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989078/show-hide-dropdown-menu-on-hover-mouseout-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, put the button and the menu inside the same container, and apply the `.hover()` effect on the whole container. This way, even if you leave the button and start hovering over the menu, you're still hovering the same container, so it won't fade out.

Demo :

```js
$(".list-container").hover(function() {
  $(this).find(".dropdown-column").fadeToggle()
});

$(".dropdown-column").click( () => alert("Clicked") );
```

```css
.nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.list-container .menuLink {
  border: blue dashed 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.list-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.dropdown-column {
  display: none;
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav">
  <div class="list-container">
    <a class="menuLink">View List 1</a>
    <div class="dropdown-column">
      <div><a href="#">Item 1</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Item 2</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Item 3</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Item 4</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="list-container">
    <a class="menuLink">View List 2</a>
    <div class="dropdown-column">
      <div><a href="#">Item 7</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Item 8</a></div>
      <div><a href="#">Item 9</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

the hover effect must be placed on a container commun for both the button and the div that appears.

```html
<div class="drop-container">
  <div class="drop-button">
  </div>
  <div class="drop-content">
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.drop-container:hover .drop-content {
  display: initial;
}
.drop-container .drop-content {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
```

Or just see: [show/hide dropdown menu on hover/mouseout using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/989078/show-hide-dropdown-menu-on-hover-mouseout-using-jquery)